# How to add search functionality to the SearchAppBar in Material UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks, fetch-api

So I have a basic react app that allows the user to search for and display movies from the Movie Database API.

Heres the problem: I want to link my custom React Function SearchMovies() to a material ui component, specifically the Material Ui SearchAppBar. However, I am having trouble adding this function to the Material Ui SearchAppBar.

First, my custom code that features the SearchMovies() function. The code is below:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import MovieCard from "./movieCard";

export default function SearchMovies() {
  //states = input query, movies
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

  const searchMovies = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const url = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=a2657ca16cc801deb9a65e9f7f9e3d4f&language=en-US&query=${query}&page=1&include_adult=false`;
    try {
      const res = await fetch(url);
      const data = await res.json();
      //console.log(data.results);
      setMovies(data.results);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form className="form" onSubmit={searchMovies}>
        <label className="label" htmlFor="query">
          Movie Name
        </label>

        <input
          type="text"
          className="input"
          name="query"
          placeholder="i.e. Star Wars"
          value={query}
          onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)}
        />

        <button className="button" type="Submit">
          Search
        </button>
      </form>
      <div className="card-list">
        {movies
          .filter((movie) => movie.poster_path)
          .map((movie) => (
            <MovieCard movie={movie} key={movie.id} />
          ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Second, here is the code for the Material UI SearchAppBar:

```
import React from "react";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import InputBase from "@material-ui/core/InputBase";
import { fade, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
import SearchIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Search";
import searchMovies from "./searchMovies";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  title: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    display: "none",
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      display: "block",
    },
  },
  search: {
    position: "relative",
    borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
    backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.common.white, 0.15),
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.common.white, 0.25),
    },
    marginLeft: 0,
    width: "100%",
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
      width: "auto",
    },
  },
  searchIcon: {
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 2),
    height: "100%",
    position: "absolute",
    pointerEvents: "none",
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  inputRoot: {
    color: "inherit",
  },
  inputInput: {
    padding: theme.spacing(1, 1, 1, 0),
    // vertical padding + font size from searchIcon
    paddingLeft: `calc(1em + ${theme.spacing(4)}px)`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create("width"),
    width: "100%",
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      width: "12ch",
      "&:focus": {
        width: "20ch",
      },
    },
  },
}));

export default function SearchAppBar() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            edge="start"
            className={classes.menuButton}
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography className={classes.title} variant="h5" noWrap>
            MovieZone
          </Typography>
          <div className={classes.search}>
            <div className={classes.searchIcon}>
              <SearchIcon />
            </div>
            <InputBase
              //value={query}
              //onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)}
              onSubmit={searchMovies}
              placeholder="Search…"
              classes={{
                root: classes.inputRoot,
                input: classes.inputInput,
              }}
              inputProps={{ "aria-label": "search" }}
            />
          </div>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
}
```

So how can I inject the SearchMovies() function into the Material UI SearchAppBar, so that the user can use the Material UI component to call the SearchMovies() function and display the movie results?

Answer (score 0):

You can take the reference from  an angular material table example but you have mat cards its just the matter of filtering the dataSource what you give and recall that method or just change the arrayList by constructing filter arraylist or something which you provide again to the UI component

Here is the link

https://stackblitz.com/angular/kgboooaejyn?embed=1&file=src/app/table-filtering-example.ts

you need to focus on this function

```
applyFilter(event: Event) {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }
```

You won't have a Datasource here but you can filter contents from ArrayList

Hope this idea works...!!

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/angular/kgboooaejyn?embed=1&file=src/app/table-filtering-example.ts